# Proxy pattern when an Entity is to be proxied?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, proxy

I'm trying to find the best solution for the following scenario: I have an entity A which has to be proxied. The problem is that when I do it simply by extending class A, making an abstract proxy delegating all of its behavior to the wrapped Entity, I end up getting plenty of unused fields inherited from that Entity. But at least it does not change the way persistence works.

In order not to do this, I've created an abstract superclass which contains only abstract methods (both public and protected, that's why I didn't go with an interface) and made it a superclass of both the Entity and all proxies. This solution seemed best, but it makes a lot of trouble when it comes to persistence...

I'd like to rely on the abstract superclass in my application layer (because it does not differentiate between proxied-A and non-proxied-A) but then Hibernate won't let me - entity instances cannot have a relation to the abstract class because it is not known to the persistence context. I could, of course, downcast the the entity class but it defeats the purpose...

Is there a way to make Hibernate downcast the entity for itself? I mean I could use the abstract class everywhere, but Hibernate would know it's really the entity class...

```
public abstract class AbstractA {

    public abstract void doSomethingOnA();

}


@Entity
public class EntityA extends AbstractA {

   @Id
   private Long id;

   @Column(name="column_in_a")
   private SomethingA somethingA;

   @Override
   public void doSomethingOnA() {
      somethingA.doSomething();
   }

}

public class ProxiedA extends AbstractA {

   private AbstractA wrappee;

   @Override
   public void doSomethingOnA() {
      doSomethingFirst();
      wrappee.doSomethingOnA();
   }  

}
```

The problem is I'd like to use AbstractA instead of EntityA also when it comes to persistence. Problem is that Hibernate will fail when another Entity declares a field which is of type AbstractA. I know why, the question is how to deal with it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What I tend to do is create an interface, for example User. Then I will have a POJO called something UserBean and an entity call UserEntity that both implement that interface. Then you can do one of two things: have a constructor in the entity that takes the bean and a createBean method to create the bean from the entity. I don't put a constructor for the entity in the bean class because in my scenario I have a layer that does not have JPA access, so the beans cannot have any knowledge of the entities.

Hibernate or any JPA provider will know when it gets a real UserEntity and will properly complain if you accidentally send it a UserBean. Often times I don't even have these implement the same interface. That way I can enforce that I do not accidentally send a UserEntity instead of a UserBean across the persistence boundary.

Then again, I could be misunderstanding your question because there are a lot of meanings to the word Proxy. For example, you could be talking about a lazy loading proxy as an attribute of an entity.  Or you could be talking about a remote proxy.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the code, it's a challenge to understand what you are describing. But after reading through your description, here are some thoughts:

- From an object-oriented perspective, if extending `EntityA` results in many unneeded members, your subclass does not feel like it is truly a subclass. An instance of the subclass should actually *be* an instance of `EntityA`, really only specializing the behavior and possibly extending the member variables of the `EntityA` parent class.
- From a persistence perspective, if your subclass is not going to use many of the fields that make up `EntityA`, you are faced with the problem that "unneeded" relational attributes may require special handling or some kind of work-around coding within your subclass objects.

Again, it is hard to be concrete without code to review, but it sounds like you may want to start by refactoring the members, both variables and operations, that are common to `EntityA` and your abstract class into a common parent class. The parent class could then be annotated to contain true entity attributes that are mapped to a column. From there, you could use simple Java inheritance and one of the Hibernate inheritance patterns to complete your implementation:

- **[Table per concrete subclass](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en-US/html/inheritance.html#inheritance-tableperconcreate-polymorphism)**, which may be defined using a `<class>` tag in Hibernate xml mappings, doesn't require extra handling to deal with polymorphism because Hibernate will scan the persistent classes and learn about superclasses or interfaces.
- **[Table per concrete subclass with unions](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en-US/html/inheritance.html#inheritance-tableperconcrete)**, which may be defined using a `<union-subclass>` tag in Hibernate xml mappings, works best when you don't need polymorphic queries and use (`UNION`-based) queries that may involve non-persistent interfaces (which sounds like it may be your situation).
- **[Table per concrete subclass with joins](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en-US/html/inheritance.html#inheritance-tablepersubclass)**, which may be defined using a `<joined-subclass>` tag in Hibernate xml mappings, is the best if you want (or must use) a fully normalized database schema.
- **[Table per class hierarchy](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en-US/html/inheritance.html#inheritance-tableperclass)**, which may be defined using a `<subclass>` tag in Hibernate xml mappings, is the simplest and performs best, because all of the subclasses are mapped to a single table, **but will only work if unique columns defined for a subclass may be `NULL`.**

Comment: The thing is those proxies that I mentioned are not to be persisted. They are wrapped around that single entity which does not have any sibling entity. Please see my updated question.